# Equilibrium probabilities in simple 3-state Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Consider the following problem, from Tijms's *Understanding Probability*:

> The much feared Professor Frank N. Stone gives varying versions of an oral examination in assembly line fashion, with students taking
>   the exam one after the other. Each version of the exam may be categorized as
>   difficult, normal or easy. After a difficult exam, the next exam will be difficult
>   with probability 0.2, will be normal with probability 0.5, and will be easy with
>   probability 0.3. After normal and easy exams, these probabilities are 0.5, 0.25
>   and 0.25. Let's say you take the exam without any knowledge of the difficulty
>   factor of the preceding exams. What is the probability that you will get a difficult exam? What is this probability if you know that your friend had an easy exam, five exams previously?

Let's call the states "hard exam", "medium exam", "easy exam" respectively 1, 2, 3.

The transition probability matrix is:
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix}
0.2 & 0.5 & 0.3 \\
0.5 & 0.25 & 0.25 \\
0.5 & 0.25 & 0.25
\end{bmatrix}
$$

To answer the first question, we need to compute the unique equilibrium probabilities. Let's call these $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3$ respectively for the hard, medium and easy exams.

We have to solve the linear system:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\pi_1 + \pi_2 + \pi_3 = 1 \\
\pi_2 = \frac12\pi_1 + \frac14 \pi_2 + \frac14\pi_3 \\
\pi_3 = \frac12\pi_1 + \frac14 \pi_2 + \frac14\pi_3.
\end{gathered}
$$
This is not the only choice of equations, but it should be a legit choice.
The solutions are:
$$
\pi_1 = \pi_2 = \pi_3 = \frac13.
$$
So the required probability, $\pi_1$, should be $1/3$.

For the second question, I compute the entry in the third row, first column of the matrix $P^6$. This gives a probability of 0.3856.

These results however are wrong (the probabilities should be 0.2692 and 0.3836). What am I doing wrong?

Edit: reading the answer by @CoolRobloxKid12 I realized that the linear system is wrong: it should be written by columns, not by rows:

$$
\begin{gathered}
\pi_1 + \pi_2 + \pi_3 = 1 \\
\pi_1 = \frac15\pi_1 + \frac12 \pi_2 + \frac12\pi_3 \\
\pi_2 = \frac12\pi_1 + \frac14 \pi_2 + \frac14\pi_3.
\end{gathered}
$$

The solutions are:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\pi_1=\frac{5}{13} & \pi_2=\frac{9}{26} & \pi_3=\frac{7}{26},
\end{gathered}
$$
and indeed $\frac{7}{26}$ is about 0.2692.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so from how I learned this, the transition matrix $P$ has column-sums adding up to 1 and I treat $x^{k + 1} = Px^k$, where $k$ is the $k$th step. This means the $P$ that I'm using is the transpose of your $P$, and I'll denote it $P_0$.

1. To calculate equilibrium solutions, find the eigenvector whose eigenvalue is 1 for $P_0$ and scale it so that its terms sum to 1. That means solving the linear system  (You're finding Null($P_0 - \lambda I$) where $\lambda = 1$): $$-0.8x_1 + 0.5x_2 + 0.5x_3 = 0$$ $$0.5x_1 -0.75x_2 + 0.25x_3 = 0$$ $$0.3x_1 + 0.25x_2 -0.75x_3 = 0$$
   Then scale your solution so the terms sum up to 1.
2. Find $x^6 = P_0^6x^0$. Here, $x^0 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ since the test 5 iterations ago was easy. The first entry of $x^6$ should be the probability that the upcoming exam will be hard.

Comment: I just quickly did it in matlab and found the first entry of $x^5 = .3856$ just like you did. Are you sure that that's not the right answer? Furthermore, I found that .2692 was the equilibrium probability of an easy exam, and that .3846 was the equilibrium probability of a difficult exam. I might be wrong in all this, but I'm pretty sure I did this right. Maybe your answer key is wrong.

Comment: Just realized we should be finding $x^6$ based on the wording. I get .3843 for the first term of $x^6$ (this still doesn't match your key, however).

Comment: Right, the linear system should be written columnwise. I wrote the solution in the original post.